# Heatwave with Visual Studio 2022 post build script build properties not available

Tags: wix4, heatwave

I have a HeatWave application installer project using the VS Heatwave extension and need to run a script in the post build event.

Unfortunately it seems the build properties are not available to the script.

For example:

```
echo $(ProjectDir)
```

returns

`echo on` instead of the project directory.

Can anyone confirm whether these build properties should be available to the pre or post build scripts for these Wii Heatwave projects in VS2022.

Or is there any other way to access these properties.